# Como forçar redirecionamento HTTP para HTTPS no NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Estou implantando um aplicativo feito com o *nuxt.js*. Para hospedagem, estou usando o *Digital Ocean* + *Server Pilot*.

Estou tendo problemas para forçar o redirecionamento de *HTTP* para *HTTPS*. Abaixo está a configuração *nginx* que estou usando.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name            admin.domain.com;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
server {
    listen    443 ssl default_server;
    listen    [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate_key    ssl/_default.key;
    ssl_certificate        ssl/_default.crt;
    return    444;
}
```

Se acessar `https://admin.domain.com`, ele funciona; se acessar `http://admin.domain.com`, ele não redirecionar para *https* e recebo um aviso de "não seguro", o cadeadinho vermelho

> NOTA: Gostaria de configurar/resolver isso do bloco `server`, porque no futuro terei outros servidores, por exemplo `blog.domain.com`

Answer (score 2):

Na sua `server{ listen: 80; ...` *(http)* você pode fazer o seguinte:

```bsh
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name            admin.domain.com;

    # Use isso ou ele dentro do location / {...}
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
    #      ^
    #      Diz para o browser o link foi Movido Permanentemente 

    # location / {
    #       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # }
}
```

<sup>**NOTA: Se um `POST` for feito para o HTTP esse método de redirecionamento não vai enviar os dados para o HTTPS**</sup>

<sub>Referencias: 

[Serverfault - In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](https://serverfault.com/a/337893/441017)

[NGINX - Pitfalls and Common Mistakes#Taxing Rewrites](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites)

[Wikipédia - HTTP Código de status 301](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Olá, consegui redirecionar para https usando a condição abaixo dentro de `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {

    ...

    if ($scheme = http) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```